# WSClient++ with Android

Tags: android, soap, wsdl

I am considering buy wsclient++, anyone recommend this?

The demo project apparently generated the files, but I still got some erros, I dont know if is a library problem or because it is a demo.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ask the Support http://wsclient.neurospeech.com/support/, they should help you, if the want to sell this product. This support-request maybe gives you also an insight how good their customer care will be, if you buy this product :-)